# VB.NET Me.Close() causing the application to throw a "has stopped working" message

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, executable, exe

I am not very experienced with VB.NET but I have to build an application using it in order to communicate with some software.  Basically, I need to be able to call this exe and have it run to perform some tasks, then close itself down.
I have the tasks running on page load but since I don't want the application to actually open, I use a Me.Close() to close it once it's finished the tasks.  So, the whole thing works great (the tasks are even performed) except the Me.Close() causes a message to come up saying the application "has stopped working."
Any ideas why this is happening?  Is it because I'm trying to close it while it's loading itself?
Any suggestions on how to achieve this in a different way?
I am forced to perform these tasks in VB, so please don't just say I should not be using VB.NET for this.  I know I shouldn't be but I have to.
Ok, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't apologize; there's nothing wrong with VB.NET.  Anyone who told you so is probably confusing it with VB6 or earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the application to open, then don't use a WinForms application (which I am assuming you are using). Instead, create a Console project, and place your code in the Main subroutine. The program will then run on the command line and close immediately when finished.

Comment: +1 for this. VB.NET is hiding the main method for you in a WinForms app. You can actually still have a main method for a WinForms app.
If you don't want the console window to open also, then just take the console app, look at the project properties, and turn it to a Windows Application, then the console should not apear, but then you will have no where to put status messages, and such.
A Windows Application, is really just a main method (basicly) like this: Application.Run(new MyForm)

Comment: +1: And to think, I almost suggested using `Application.Exit`... I feel stupid for not even thinking "wait, why's there a window?"

Comment: Actually, I have to use an OCX tool which unfortunately is tied to a GUI component, so I wasn't able to put it into a console application.  I do see that that's the right way.  But, I was still able to get it to work like a console of sorts by using System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit() once I was finished with the tasks.  Thanks for the help though everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a VB.Net console application that performs the tasks. This way the app will just run its tasks and then shut itself down without having to explicitly tell it to.